# Is the word "to" necessary when you list actions?

Tags: word-usage, lists

Which one is correct for a list with "objectives" or "goals" (e.g. for resume or something formal)?

- Improve something
- Learn more about something
- Work with something

OR

- To improve something
- To learn more about something
- To work with something

If the last one were the case...Is not too repetitive?

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience, it depends on how you approach the list.  For example, there can be this:

> My goal is:
>
> - To improve something
> - To learn more about something
> - To work on something

Or it can be this:

> My goal is **to**:
>
> - Improve something
> - Learn more about something
> - Work on something

If you include the **to** before the list of verbs/goals, then you don't need it in the list.  If it's left out, then it should be included in the list (if the list is made of verb infinitives).